# How to activate/deactivate elements on interface according to checkbox with no code in AppleascriptObjC

Tags: xcode, applescript-objc

I know how to do this programmatically, but I saw some similar operations when you want to copy a value of text field to another with no use of code, the problem I have many images and, I don't want to make outlets for all of them, so if that possible it wild be great.

Answer (score 0):

No, do it programmatically.

Create UIImageView and UITextfield programmatically and set their tag and value with a loop. That's best for you. This is not good to take many UIImageView and Textfield if you have many image and text. Use the tag to reuse the value/text.

No other best way except this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Interface Editor's **Bindings Inspector** to bind the **Enabled**/**Hidden** property of the various UI items to a property in your script.  Bind to the script class that has the property, and set the **Model Key Path** to the name of the script's property.

You can also use the **Value Transformer** to negate the boolean value of a binding if you need to change the way the property gets toggled.  Note that if you want to programmatically change the property value, you also need to use the keyword **my** or a setter method to keep the appropriate Key-Value Observing notifications up to date.

Comment: I know how to do that programmatically, I am asking if there another way on interface with no code